# Is there a way to change a css style based upon an ng-if expression related to a binding object

Tags: angularjs

As the title says, i'd like to know if it's possible to change a css style based upon a binding value using ng-if.

For example:

ng-if="value == 'RED'" <-- then change the css style of that value to red and so.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ng-if will conditionally add/remove the element from the DOM. You could use

```
ng-style="{color: myColor}"
```

Or you could try ng-class

```
ng-class="{someCssErrorClass: error}"
```

Comment: ok, but that would turn all my rows in a single color, what if i want a row to be red and others green depending on its binding value?

Comment: forget it :P done this on the controller for (var poss = 0; poss < $scope.prodList.length; poss++) {
  if($scope.prodList[poss].stock === 'NO STOCK') {
   $scope.prodList[poss].stock_color = 'red';
  }else{
   $scope.prodList[poss].stock_color = 'green';
  }
 } and worked really well hahaha

Answer (score 0):

End up doing the following, from the controller part where i get the factory http.get data object, just iterated over the objs and added a new value which i use in the view afterwards. Plane and simple.

```
for (var poss = 0; poss < $scope.prodList.length; poss++) {
        if($scope.prodList[poss].stock === 'NO STOCK') {
            $scope.prodList[poss].stock_color = 'red';
        }else{
            $scope.prodList[poss].stock_color = 'green';
        }
    }
```